# CakePHP: Debug messages not shown

Tags: cakephp

I have in `config/app_local.php` this code:

```
return [
    /*
     * Debug Level:
     *
     * Production Mode:
     * false: No error messages, errors, or warnings shown.
     *
     * Development Mode:
     * true: Errors and warnings shown.
     */
    'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
    'DebugKit' => [ 'forceEnable' => TRUE], 
...
```

Before I had this warning in the log file:

```
warning: DebugKit is disabling itself as your host `my.example.com` is not in the known safe list of 
   top-level-domains (localhost, invalid, test, example, local). 
   If you would like to force DebugKit on use the `DebugKit.forceEnable` Configure option.
```

After I set the above code the warning has gone but I still don't see the CakePHP debug window when an error occurs. I see only this:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of App\Controller\ErrorController::beforeRender(Cake\Event\EventInterface $event) 
  must be compatible with App\Controller\AppController::beforeRender(Cake\Event\EventInterface $event): 
  void in /var/www/vhosts/example.ocm/my.example.com/src/Controller/ErrorController.php on line 54
```

What am I still missing, doing wrong? The debug message is only in the log file, but I would like to see it also in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message indicates, the prototypes of the two functions do not match. The `: void` on the AppController indicates that the function won't return anything. The ErrorController is missing this. They need to match.

Comment: OMG. PhpStorm warned me about the missing return type, so I added `void`.

I think, this will never be updated due to the new PHP versions which are more and more restrictive. It would break every page. So I have to ignore it in PhpStorm and in the source code. Thank you very much, I was too blind to see the small difference!